# Jython creates file in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc failed

Tags: windows, jython

In my RF scripts, I need to modify the hosts file under c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc to finish my test job. But the scripts fail with ERROR 20047, I tried to create file in another folder, it was OK. I get the conclusion that it only doesn't work in folder etc, it seems that I do have the permission to create/modify hosts file. I modified the owner of folder etc and granted all permission to the current user and tried again. It still does not work.

BTW: The RF scripts run with jython. I find that It works while I use python to create/modify hosts in folder etc.

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Just a guess, could it be a read only problem? On my windows 7 `CACLS hosts` gives BUILTIN\Users:(ID)R

Comment: @Marichyasana seem that it is a read only problem. Every time after I removed the readonly tag from the etc folder, it came back again automatically.